# Cordova Camera iOS Issue: NOT_FOUND_ERR

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am using the `cordova-plugin-camera` cordova plugin (version 4.0.3), wrapped by the Ionic Native wrapper for Ionic 4 `@ionic-native/camera@4`.  I'm using it to capture a photo (regular or from library), and move it into my app storage area for saving/sending.  Things work great on Android.  On iOS I continue to get a `NOT_FOUND_ERR` back when trying to grab the FILE_URI that comes back from the capture.

Below is how I'm capturing the image, which works just fine.  The camera launches, I snap (or choose) a photo, and I get a file URI back (file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{guid}/tmp/XYZ.jpg).  Then something as simple as doing a `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl` on this resulting file URI will bomb with `NOT_FOUND_ERR`.  Any advice?

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  sourceType: (isFromLibrary) ? this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY : this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
  targetWidth: (isForDocScan) ? desiredWidth + 500 : desiredWidth,
  targetHeight: (isForDocScan) ? desiredHeight + 500 : desiredHeight
}

let result = null;
try {
  result = await this.camera.getPicture(options);
}
catch (err) {
  this.loggingService.error('Error getting photo', err);
}
```

Comment: does the camera throw the error or the `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl` ??

Comment: resolveLocalFilesystemUrl does.  The camera capture seems to work, and give back a file path to the captured photo.  Either I don't have access to the file provided, or it isn't valid?

Comment: can you include the uri from camera and how you call `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl` ?

Comment: Yup. `let originalFile = await this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(imagePath);` And the URI is of the form of `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{guid}/tmp/XYZ.jpg`

Comment: I just changed the `destinationType` on the `CameraOptions` to use `this.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI`, and I'm seeing some progress.  Not sure if it's normal to not be able to use `FILE_URI` for iOS?

Comment: can you try with `destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI` ??

Comment: yep, the doc does not say that,but  when you have a look, they do show ios output for NATIVE_URI. let me know if it works

Comment: Funny timing.  We had a similar thought.  It does seem to work this way.  Any idea if `NATIVE_URI` is required for iOS for some reason?  If you can explain the "why" and throw it in an answer, I'd be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: what is your source? I mean when you get this error, its unclear since you have `isFromLibrary`

Comment: To answer your question, I was getting this error with `PHOTOLIBRARY` and `CAMERA` (before adjusting the `DestinationType`, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some hiccups when using the `Camera.DestinationType` configs. The below are the outputs when you use `FILE_URI` and `NATIVE_URI`

**Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI**

```
'file://' ios
'content://' android
```

**Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI**

```
'assets-library://' ios
'content://' android
```

Although this is the outputs, this is internally related to your `sourceType`. What this means is that, if your `sourceType` is the camera, you should be using `FILE_URI` as the output is obtained from the temporary storage, while if you are using photogallery, your output needs to be obtained from the library, which is why its recommended you use `NATIVE_URI`

Comment: Thanks.  I can confirm that if I use the `DestinationType.NATIVE_URI` on iOS it does work.  This seems to be needed for both `PHOTOLIBRARY` and `CAMERA` sources.  I swear this used to work with `FILE_URI` at one point on iOS.  Maybe I picked up some plugin/package changes without me realizing it at some point.

Comment: One other note on this.  I found that a call to `camera.cleanup()` impacted this significantly.  I was actually able to go back to using `DestinationType.FILE_URI` just by moving my call to `camera.cleanup()`.  So seemingly this cleanup seems to act differently on Android/iOS, and it does impact `PHOTOLIBRARY` use, which doesn't match the documentation claims.

Comment: But, i think the behaviour for cleanup is correct as its meant for memory management. Using camera creates temporary files, and using base64 is prone to memory leaks, which needs to be addressed by the cleanup method. Using photo gallery however is not intended to create any memory issues.

Comment: The documentation states **Applies only when the value of Camera.sourceType equals Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA and the Camera.destinationType equals Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI.**.  On iOS I noticed cleanup impacting functionality when the Source & Destination Type were different.  So I'm just saying the docs don't seem to match what I saw (on iOS anyway).