Ionic project updated to Android 14 support but now Camera only opens after several clicks
I recently updated my Ionic project to support Android 14. However, after the update, I’m encountering an issue where the camera plugin (cordova-plugin-camera) only opens after several clicks on the button. Before the update, the camera would open immediately after a single click.
takePicture(record){
    console.log('takePicture:'+record);
    const popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions = {
      x: 250,
      y: 430,
      width: 100,
      height: 200,
      arrowDir: this.camera.PopoverArrowDirection.ARROW_LEFT
    };
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 50,
      targetWidth: 1024,
      targetHeight: 1024,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      //sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
      sourceType: record ? this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA : this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, //FILE_URI not working on ios (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633601/cordova-camera-ios-issue-not-found-err)
      popoverOptions: popoverOptions,
      correctOrientation: true
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((image) => {
      // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
      // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
      //this.videoUrl = videoUri;
      //console.log('image:'+image);
      //this.imageUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+image;
      console.log('takenPicture:'+image);
      console.log('Image:'+image);
      this.selectedImageUri = image;
      if(this.selectedImageUri.indexOf('?')>0){
        this.selectedImageUri = this.selectedImageUri.substring(0, this.selectedImageUri.indexOf('?'));
      }
      this.loadFile(this.selectedImageUri);

    }, (err) => {
     // Handle error
    });
  }

Steps I’ve Taken:
Updated all the necessary plugins to ensure compatibility with Android 14.
Verified that the cordova-plugin-camera is the latest version.
Checked permissions and ensured that the app has camera access.
Tested on multiple devices. This issue only in Android 14 devices.
Issue:
After clicking the button that triggers the getPicture method, the camera only opens after several clicks instead of immediately.

So what does the console log say? there must be errors showing. -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
